# Trying to invoke cc compiler

Tags: c, csound

Very basic question here. I am just starting out with C coding using Csound.

I am trying to invoke the compiler via instructions from a tutorial book.

It says open console window and type this command "cc mysource.c"

This is seemingly meant to invoke the compiler but I get this error message

```
C:\Program Files\Csound6_x64\bin>cc mysource.c

'cc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to download any software to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably yes, it's windows, it won't be available just so.

Comment: You probably need to install Visual Studio 2019 with C++ workflow, create a C++ project there and add Csound as additional include and lib dirs.

Comment: You can also install cygwin or WSL with a real shell and the gcc compiler and not have to use the Windows command line.

Comment: cc is the canonical name of the c compiler on unix-like systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cc was a compiler for Unix. It doesn't come with Windows, and you probably want to use gcc instead because it is used much more. You must set up MinGW and add it to PATH. Following this guide will help: youtube.com/watch?v=sXW2VLrQ3Bs

You can then compile C using `gcc mysource.c`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I think that installer method might be dated. There's a of instructions that don't match up to what I'm seeing. Also to be sure, are you saying I should install Cygwin or just set up MinGW?

Comment: @shakamoto sorry, that's not a great guide actually. Try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXW2VLrQ3Bs

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. That seems to have gotten gcc installed. Now, when I try and run a c file in command prompt nothing actually happens. I thought it would open run the programme and give me an output. Or is that not right?

Comment: Okay, I see. It creates an .exe file and then you can run that. Got it!